# Can I put a Shimano 1x12 group set on my benotto xc 4000

Tags: drivetrain, modification, 7-speed

I just want to know if there would be any special modifications in order to make it work?

[image: stock photo of this bike]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you can continue using the saddle, pedals, and maybe the stem+handlebar and grips.   Tubes and Tyres too if you get the same size wheel.  Everything else is likely to need changing.   Cheaper to get a new bike, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If your bike has a 7 speed freewheel then no you can’t put a 1x12 system on the bike without changing the rear wheel and even then maybe no.

At a general level it depends on whether your rear wheel has or can be retrofitted with a Micro Spline freehub.

You'd need a 135mm Microspline rear hub (e.g Shimano FH-MT401) and that hub with cassette would need to fit in your frame which is not guaranteed.

All the Shimano 1x12 systems need a Micro Spline freehub to fit the 10 tooth gear.

If you’re  stuck with an HG freehub you can still use the 11 speed 11-51 Deore CS-M5100 cassette.

Comment: https://casabikes.com/products/benotto-xc-4000-front-suspension-mountain-bike confirms you're right - its definitely a 7 speed and probably a freewheel rather than a cassette.

Comment: Actually, 12s cassettes for Hyperglide hubs exist, e.g. Sunrace. The issue is that they start with 11t cogs, which affects your top gear. https://www.sunrace.com/en/products/detail/csmz901